# Import database in Wamp Server

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, wamp

I want to back up my website to localhost. Well I am new to all PHP and other things.

I opened my website and downloaded my database. Then I created a database in phpMyAdmin on localhost and installed WordPress on it. Now when I try to import the database it shows the follwing error:

```
error!! #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I think I made some mistakes. Is there anything that I should do with selecting collection or something like that while creating the database?

Comment: Delete all tables from wordpress and rerun the import. (It should create the tables too)

Comment: it imports and i can see posts on php my admin but the when i open local host and that particular site it shows nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you did your backup without ticking the add DROP TABLE option, or when you try to do the restore more than once.

Never mind, just use phpMyAdmin to drop ( thats delete ) all the tables within that database and try the resore again.

Comment: sorry! i couldn't get it..did you mean to delete the database in wamp and restore the database which was obtained from website? well i did that and nothing shows up when i try to open website in wamp..

Comment: I meant drop the TABLES and leave the database as it is. Is there data in the tables when yo look with phpMyAdmin. If yes then you need to check the apps config is using the corrrect database, userid and password. Also did you setup the userid and password in MySQL.

Comment: yes i dropped the tables such as: wp_commentmeta wp_posts wp_terms..etc. I dropped all the tables and imported the files. Yes i can see new tables and there are posts which i wanted but i can't open wordpress. wordpress doesn't show up...

Comment: I assume that your php code must need to connect to the database. This requires a databasename and a userid and a password (MySQL account) created that has the correct privileges to tat database.

Comment: can you tell about that ids? well when i have a database the what is password and userid?

Comment: There is a file in the root of a WP site called `wp-config.php` the first few lines tell WP 1. the database name, 2. The userid to use 3. the password to use, to connect to the mysql database. You need to create this user in MySQL with that password and make sure this new account has the correct access priviledges on that database. And make sure you have called that database the same name as is used in this file. **Sounds like you need to read the WordPress site documentation**

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what it means is that you have 2 things with the PRIMARY number of 1, the table must most likely be setup with an auto_increment this is where you issue is.

Comment: yeah i also think so.. but how can i make it work.. well i am new to php and other coding stuffs

Comment: if you remove the column no references to this entry will work any more

Answer (score 0):

I had been facing the same problem for long in WAMP phpMyAdmin server. I went to so many sites and forums and guru's help but most didn't make sense. Some suggested to "add/mark add drop table" and some to "use update in place of insert". These answers were so lackadaisical and untechnical. They never hit on real problem. The real problem lies in WAMP phpMyAdmin. There seems to be a bug in it, which inserts TWO additional lines in the SQL file when one exports an existing database. These lines are the lower two of:

```
--
-- Database: `xyz`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `xyz` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `xyz`;
```

What happens really is when you export an existing database and then create a blank database there with some other name and then try to export that existing database SQL file is the following: Due to those additional lines, SQL Server tries to create a database with the same name. Hence the duplicate key problem. All you need to do: Open the SQL file with Notepad Plus or any other editor and delete said two lines, keeping only:

```
--
-- Database: `xyz`
--
```

Then save the file and import it to your blank database with whatever name you want. Hopefully it will solve the problem.